# XPath: "string list" except "string"?

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I am using XPath together with XSLT (both version 2.0). I'd like to get a list of strings except for a single string:

```
<xsl:param name="lang" select="'de'"/>
<xsl:variable name="all-languages" select="('en','de','fr')"/>
<xsl:variable name="other-languages" select="$all-languages except $lang "/>
```

For a documentation project, I'd like to generate the documentation in `$lang` and link to all other languages. So it would be nice to get (in the example above) `$other-languages` to `('de','fr')` and use `<xsl:for-each>` to iterate over the languages except for the string in `$lang`.

`except` seems to work only for nodes. What is the nicest solution for the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simpler and more efficient**:

```
$all-languages[. ne $lang]
```

Comment: Simpler, yes, but surely not more efficient. That needs to compare every language to $lang by evaluating an expression, while index-of can just perform native comparisons until it finds the first match.

Comment: @BeniBela, Not true -- `index-of()` needs to do a full scan of the sequence. Then `remove()` does another scan. Additional memory may be needed for the index-sequence. The expression in this answer is evaluated just in a single scan and doesn't need any additional memory. Therefore, I expect this solution to be about twice as fast as the `remove ... index-of` solution. Everyone can conduct their own experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the language from all-languages, seems to be a good idea:

```
remove($all-languages, index-of($all-languages, $lang)))
```